# VS Code & Python -> Autocomplete missing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When writing a search, right after instantiating the actual `Search` object, auto complete works as expected. After using the `query` method, I lose the auto-complete.

If i write the code ignoring the fact that intellisense is not suggesting anything, it works ok! (assuming i wrote it correctly)

What am I doing wrong here?

To workaround this, i have a variable commented... if i need auto-complete, i uncomment it, check the auto-complete, and paste it on the appropriate spot...

Comment: What package is providing `Search`? And are you using Jedi or the language server?

Comment: Search is being provided by `elasticsearch-dsl`. And i don't know the answer for the second question... can you tell me how to get that info?

Comment: Do you have "Jedi Enabled" set?